# Hibernate creates blank entry in associated table if no values are passed with parent entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

So I have two relational tables in a database: driver and drivers_license.  I have the driver entity set up like this for the relationship with the license entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(unique = true)
private DriversLicense driversLicense;
```

Currently, if I save a new driver without any drivers license fields (so they default to null) it still creates a new entry in the drivers_license table with all null values.

Is there a way to avoid creating the blank entry in that table if it's not given?

Answer (score 0):

Remove CascadeType.ALL or change to Delete, Update.
I think we cannot change the cascade behaviour at runtime.